# Error: package or namespace load failed for ggplot2 and for data.table

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I am not able to open install the ggplot2 and data.table packages.
It gives me the following error (example for ggplot2)

```
> library(ggplot2)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

I was able to work fine with these 2 packages before I closed my R session. Now it shows me this error each time I try to run it.

I have also tried to remove and re-install it, but without success.

```
remove.packages(c("ggplot2", "data.table"))
install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)
install.packages('data.table', dep = TRUE)
```

I am not sure what's wrong

Comment: Your problem is not the package ggplot2, but the package Rcpp.

Comment: Read the error message and you'll get the solution to your problem. It is a good idea to use `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)`.

Comment: oops.  Maybe data.table then?  Or maybe there was something unreproducible going on and this was a waste of a bounty.

Comment: ggplot2 depends  on five dozen other things some of which (scales ?) use compiled code.  So the fact that ggplot2 is R-only is a red herring.

Comment: I had this same problem after installing `Rcpp`. Nothing else would load. Just did `install.packages('Rcpp', dependencies = TRUE)` again and didn't have to mess with any of my other packages.

Answer (score 114):

This solved the issue:

```
remove.packages(c("ggplot2", "data.table"))
install.packages('Rcpp', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('data.table', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: `dependencies=TRUE` is not necessary, this install Suggested deps which are not mandatory for R packages

Comment: This did not solve the issue for me

Answer (score 11):

After a wild goose chase with tons of Google searches and burteforce attempts, I think I found how to solve this problem.

**Steps undertaken to solve the problem:**

1. Uninstall R
2. Reinstall R
3. Install ggplot with the dependencies argument to install.packages set to TRUE

   `install.packages("ggplot2",dependencies = TRUE)`
4. The above step still does NOT include the Rcpp dependency so that has to be manually installed using the following command

   `install.packages("Rcpp")`

However, while the above command successfully downloads Rcpp, for some reason, it fails to explode the ZIP file and install it in my R's library folder citing the following error:

> package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Warning in
>   install.packages :   unable to move temporary installation
>   ‘C:\Root_Prgs\Data_Science_SW\R\R-3.2.3\library\file27b8ef47b6d\Rcpp’
>   to ‘C:\Root_Prgs\Data_Science_SW\R\R-3.2.3\library\Rcpp’
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>     C:\Users\MY_USER_ID\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp25XQ0S\downloaded_packages

5. Note that the above output says "Warning" but actually, it is an indication of failure to install the Rcpp package successfully within the repository. I then used the **Tools-->Install packages-->** From ZIP file and pointed to the location of the "downloaded binary packages" in the message above -

`C:\Users\MY_USER_ID\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp25XQ0S\downloaded_packages\Rcpp_0.12.3.zip`

6. This led to successful installation of Rcpp in my R\R-3.2.3\library folder, thereby ensuring that Rcpp is now available when I attempt to load the library for ggplot2. **I could not do this step in the past because my previous installation of R would throw error stating that Rcpp cannot be imported. However, the same command worked after I uninstalled and reinstalled R, which is ODD.**

   > install.packages("C:/Users/MY_USER_ID/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp25XQ0S/downloaded_packages/Rcpp_0.12.3.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
   >       package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked`
7. I was finally able to load the ggplot2 library successfully.

   `library(ggplot2)`

Comment: that's not really "solving the problem", that's like murder plus escape to the other side of the planet under a new identity ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Faced same issue and solved by :

```
remove.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 7):

I also faced the same problem and

```
remove.packages(c("ggplot2", "data.table"))
install.packages('Rcpp', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
```

these commands did not work for me. What I found was that it was showing a warning message that it could not move temporary installation `C:\Users\User_name\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\abcd1234\Rcpp` to `C:\Users\User_name\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\Rcpp`.

I downloaded the Rcpp zip file from the link given and unziped it and copied it inside `C:\Users\User_name\Documents\R\win-library\3.3` and then

```
library(Rcpp)
library(ggplot2)
```

worked. I did not have to uninstall R. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me too. Though I had to manually change the package name to 'Rcpp' in the Windows file directory for it to match in R and move the files one level up in the Windows file directory.  Glad I didn't have to uninstall everything.

Answer (score 6):

when you see

> Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)

answer no

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
install.packages('ggplot2')
install.packages('data.table')
```

Comment: Can't you install them all in a single command? Also, doesn't they just need install Rcpp? Or specify `dependencies = TRUE` when installing in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the package "tidyverse". I solved the problem with 
1. uninstalling the package "Rcpp" and "tidyverse" 
2. reinstalling "Rcpp" and answering the following questions during the installation process:

```
Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)
```

with

```
no
```

3. reinstalling "tidyverse".

Answer (score 1):

I tried the steps mentioned in the earlier posts but without any success. However, what worked for me was uninstalling R completely and then deleting the R folder which files in the documents folder, so basically everything do with R except the scripts and work spaces I had saved. I then reinstalled R and ran

```
remove.packages(c("ggplot2", "data.table"))
install.packages('Rcpp', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('data.table', dependencies = TRUE)
```

This rather crude method somehow worked for me.

Comment: I did something similar and just copied my relevant files into a new folder and made a new project. Worked quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the listed solutions above but nothing worked.
This is what worked for me.

1. Look at the complete error message which you get when you use library(ggplot2).
2. It lists a couple of packages which are missing or have errors.
3. Uninstall and reinstall them.
4. ggplot should work now with a warning for version.

Answer (score 0):

These steps work for me:

1. Download the Rcpp manually from WebSite
   (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html)
2. unzip the folder/files to "Rcpp" folder
3. Locate the "library" folder under R install directory Ex:
   C:\R\R-3.3.1\library
4. Copy the "Rcpp" folder to Library folder.

**Good to go!!!**

```
library(Rcpp)
library(ggplot2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, i had to uninstall R from brew `brew uninstall --force R` and then head over to the [R website and download and install it from there](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but when running in a jupyter R notebook in an Anaconda environment.

The problem presented in such a way that any R notebook opened would instantly die and would not allow cell execution.  The error would show up with each failed automated attempt to start the kernel:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
```

To solve this, I ran as admin/sudo: `conda install -c r r-rcpp`, restarted the kernel, and everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for joining the party late, You can install any package in RStudio by downloading the zip file from the [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) website and running the below snippet in the console,

```
install.packages('~/Downloads/Rcpp_1.0.8.tgz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')
```