# loading 3rd party 'R' packages in windows 10

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, windows-10

I can't seem to get downloaded packages into the right place so that they work. I open the RGui as administrator and type:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", lib="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library")
```

it returns:

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\...path...Temp\RtmpcLuCYn\downloaded_packages
```

which is not the place it should have gone to which is the first problem. So I try to load the package from this location:

```
library(ggplot2, lib.loc="C:/...path...Temp/RtmpcLuCYn/downloaded_packages")
```

and it returns:

```
Error in library(ggplot2, lib.loc = "C:/...path...Temp/RtmpcLuCYn/downloaded_packages") :
```

`there is no package called ‘ggplot2’`

so I figure let's try just loading from where I told it to put the file:

```
library(ggplot2, lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library")
```

unsurprisingly this didn't work, it returned:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

I have no idea why it sends the download to a temp location but it seems reasonable that this is the cause of the problem. I have administrator access. I have also tried:

adding "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library" as an environment variable

adding R_LIBS_USER to user variables with the value 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library'

just downloading with the command:

```
install.packages('ggplot2')
```

the errors and returns are identical

Any further advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: try `install.packages("ggplot2",dependencies=TRUE)` ?

Comment: i.e.. possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table

Comment: I tried install.packages("ggplot2",dependencies=TRUE) but the same problem persists, i.e. it is downloaded to a temp location. This is not a duplicate question: This question relates to the download being installed to a temp folder from which the package can't be retrieved. It downloads here despite being instructed to download to the R-libraries folder. The solutions in the link you have posted don't work for this problem. Thanks for your effort though

Comment: The sourcecode or binary is _downloaded_ into the temp location. But it is _installed_ into `lib.loc`. Try in a fresh session first `install.packages("ggplot2",dependencies=TRUE)`, then `library(ggplot2)`.

Comment: This doesn't work either, it still says "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’". I get the feeling that the download needs to go to the right place and it isn't even though I am telling it where it should download to.