# RE: Loading ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try to load ggplot2 I receive the message:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
```

I unable to find this message in previous answers. Can someone help, thanks.

I've downloaded everything from scratch, but I still get same message each time I load an RStudio project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: package or namespace load failed for ggplot2 and for data.table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table)

Comment: I still get same message each time I load an RStudio project.

Comment: I would try `sessionInfo()` make sure Rcpp is actually attached, if its not load it manually then try loading ggplot2. Assuming it is loaded or this doesn't help I'd try completely uninstalling and reinstalling R. Also maybe check and see if you get the same error working without RStudio.

Comment: Will give that go, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information about the error, this worked for me when it happened in my code

```
install.packages('Rcpp', dependencies = TRUE)
```