# Issues loading R libraries in Jupyter

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I am trying to load R libraries such as ggplot2, qtlcharts, scatterD3 etc. into my jupyter notebook but getting the follwoing error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2'

Has anybody faced similar issue? How do we solve it?

Note: I tried reinstalling the libraries (with different CRAN mirrors) and updating all the current packages as well but in vain.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table

Comment: Hi @Hack-R , I tried doing everything suggested in the discussion but in vain. I even re-installed Anaconda but that too gave a short-term relief. As soon as I installed the above mentioned libraries (and the htcharts library), the R kernel crashed.Is there any problem between html5/svg visualization libraries and the jupyter R kernel? How can I keep the libraries without crashing the R kernel in jupyter? Please help

Comment: @avinax, if you found a crashbug then report it as a [Jupyter issue] https://github.com/jupyter/help). Is this still occurring? What versions of R, Jupyter, packages, OS?

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem before
you should go to folder which Anaconda3>Lib>R and delete rlang folder
and install rlang on jupyter
hope you handle it