# Error: Package or namespace load failed

Tags: r, install.packages, lazyeval

I am getting the following error when I am loading a few libraries in R:

> library(forecast)
>   Error : object ‘f_eval’ is not exported by 'namespace:lazyeval'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘forecast’ was built under R version 3.3.2 
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’
>
> library(tsoutliers)
>   Error : object ‘f_eval’ is not exported by 'namespace:lazyeval'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘tsoutliers’ was built under R version 3.3.2 
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tsoutliers’

I have tried reinstalling the packages but it didn't help. Also, I was able to use the forecast package previously but I started facing this error post the installation of tsoutliers package.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: package or namespace load failed for ggplot2 and for data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the job for you:

```
install.packages('lazyeval')
```

In the future, try and provide a bit more about your system and install, using the output from:

```
sessionInfo()
```