# Getting a 'package or namespace load failed' error message while installing R packages

Tags: r

Trying to install tidyverse and skimr and getting the same error message as below:

```
>Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘skimr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 object 'pkgInfo' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  package ‘pkgconfig’ has no 'package.rds' in Meta/
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: looks like a problem with `pkgconfig`. Try `install.packages("pkgconfig")` and make sure that works correctly first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Package or namespace load failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479272/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed)

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, installing pkgconfig worked.