# Unable to load shared object Undefined symbol in h5 package, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install h5 package in ubuntu 14.04. Before doing so, I have installed hdf5 package, updated the CPPFLAGS and LIBS flags. It is able to link to them correctly. However, after the compiling steps, it is unable to load the package and is giving an error,

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘h5’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)

sessionInfo

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_IN       
[4] LC_COLLATE=en_IN     LC_MONETARY=en_IN    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_IN       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C        
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

**attached base packages:**

```
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

**loaded via a namespace (and not attached):**

```
[1] compiler_3.4.0
```

I have taken care in ensuring that all the dependent package versions are as mentioned in the package requirements.

Will be grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: unable to load shared object '/home/chaitanya/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/h5/libs/h5.so':
      /home/chaitanya/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/h5/libs/h5.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN2H59ExceptionE

Comment: Hi, I am not an R specialist but here it looks to be a very similar case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table 

I hope it helps