# Error in loading package SASxport: object ‘label<-.data.frame’ is not exported by 'namespace:Hmisc'

Tags: r, sas, install.packages, hmisc

I'm trying to read data in the XPT format into R (the format can be found for example in the [NHANES data](https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/Search/DataPage.aspx?Component=Questionnaire&CycleBeginYear=2015)). I found two functions doing this:

```
library("Hmisc")
sasxport.get("C:/path/file.XPT")
```

and

```
library("SASxport")
read.xport("C:/path/file.XPT")
```

The `sasxport.get` works, so I'm basically fine, but still inquisitive enough to understand (and solve) the following error: after the installation of the `SASxport` package, I cannot load it. When I run `library("SASxport")`, I get the error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘SASxport’:
 object ‘label<-.data.frame’ is not exported by 'namespace:Hmisc'
```

Adopting [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table), I also ran

```
remove.packages(c("SASxport", "Hmisc"))
install.packages('Hmisc', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('SASxport', dependencies = TRUE)
```

what did not change the error message.

---

This is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Hmisc_4.1-1     ggplot2_2.2.1   Formula_1.2-2   survival_2.41-3 lattice_0.20-35

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14        pillar_1.0.1        compiler_3.4.3      RColorBrewer_1.1-2  plyr_1.8.4         
 [6] base64enc_0.1-3     iterators_1.0.9     tools_3.4.3         rpart_4.1-11        digest_0.6.13      
[11] tibble_1.4.1        gtable_0.2.0        htmlTable_1.11.1    checkmate_1.8.5     rlang_0.1.6        
[16] icenReg_2.0.7       Matrix_1.2-12       foreach_1.4.4       rstudioapi_0.7      yaml_2.1.16        
[21] gridExtra_2.3       coda_0.19-1         stringr_1.2.0       cluster_2.0.6       knitr_1.18         
[26] htmlwidgets_0.9     grid_3.4.3          nnet_7.3-12         data.table_1.10.4-3 foreign_0.8-69     
[31] latticeExtra_0.6-28 magrittr_1.5        scales_0.5.0        backports_1.1.2     codetools_0.2-15   
[36] htmltools_0.3.6     splines_3.4.3       colorspace_1.3-2    stringi_1.1.6       acepack_1.4.1      
[41] lazyeval_0.2.1      munsell_0.4.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last update of `SASxport` happend nearly two years ago (2016-03-11). So the `Hmisc` package it imports might have changed in the meantime. Looking up the [Hmisc archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Hmisc/) I found the version number on 2016-03-11 to be 3.17-2. So installing this version fixes the problem:

```
library("devtools")
install_version("Hmisc", version = "3.17-2")
```

Two reasons speak against using `SASxport` in this case:

1. You need to use a old version of a package which might happer your work in later steps.
2. `SASxport` needs `Hmisc` for a task that `Hmisc` can do already by itself, so `SASxport` is expendable when reading in XPT files.

Comment: I had the same problem but but I got an error message when running `install_version("Hmisc", version = "3.17-2")`. This is it: `Trying https://cran.csiro.au
Trying http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin
Downloading package from url: https://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib/Archive/Hmisc/Hmisc_3.17-2.tar.gz
Installation failed: Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10015 milliseconds` how do we solve this?