# Can't load the r package 'arulesViz' because no package called 'viridis'

Tags: r, viridis

I want to use 'arulesViz' to visualize association rule, but when I load the package, r give me an error:

`>library(arulesViz)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arulesViz’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘viridis’`

I install 'viridis' independently before 'arulesViz' but when I use `library(viridis)` I still get the same error which said there is no such package.

How can I successfully install 'arulesViz'?

Comment: Are you able to  load `viridis` i.e. `library(viridis)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5br%5d%20%22there%20is%20no%20package%20called%22%20is%3aquestion

Comment: See if solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table) helps

Comment: make sure you have `dependencies = TRUE` on when you `install.packages('arulesViz')`, see `?install.packages`

Answer (score 2):

As the comments suggest, you could install the library with dependencies, like this:

```
install.packages("arulesViz", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: I have removed the previous one I installed and reinstall the package as your suggestion. However, I still get the same error...

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the paths. Can you have a look here: https://www.reddit.com/r/R_Programming/comments/4c7e58/why_can_i_not_load_the_package_arulesviz_no/

Answer (score 1):

I have removed all of the packages and installed them again. Then there's no error.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by downloading the latest release from github:

```
library("devtools")
install_github("mhahsler/arulesViz")
```