# R ggplot - "Error in is_list(x) : object 'rlang_is_list' not found"

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang

I have some code from a couple of weeks ago that uses ggplot and was working without any problems. Now when I try to run the even one layer of the multi-level plot function, I get an error.

I have a dataframe that looks like this excerpt:

```
      X Year Month value         dt color id
1     1 1948   Jan   3.4 1948-01-01  TRUE  1
2     2 1948   Feb   3.8 1948-02-01  TRUE  1
3     3 1948   Mar   4.0 1948-03-01 FALSE  1
4     4 1948   Apr   3.9 1948-04-01  TRUE  1
5     5 1948   May   3.5 1948-05-01  TRUE  1
6     6 1948   Jun   3.6 1948-06-01  TRUE  1
7     7 1948   Jul   3.6 1948-07-01  TRUE  1
8     8 1948   Aug   3.9 1948-08-01  TRUE  1
9     9 1948   Sep   3.8 1948-09-01  TRUE  1
10   10 1948   Oct   3.7 1948-10-01  TRUE  1
11   11 1948   Nov   3.8 1948-11-01  TRUE  1
12   12 1948   Dec   4.0 1948-12-01 FALSE  1
13   13 1949   Jan   4.3 1949-01-01 FALSE  1
14   14 1949   Feb   4.7 1949-02-01 FALSE  1
15   15 1949   Mar   5.0 1949-03-01 FALSE  1
```

And the first part of the plot function is:

```
# create plot
ggplot() + 

        # time series line of unemployment rate
        geom_line(data=t3,
                  aes(x=dt, y=value),
                  show.legend = F)
```

And this is the error that gets thrown:

`Error in is_list(x) : object 'rlang_is_list' not found`

My hunch is that is_list() is called somewhere within the ggplot script to check if the aes arguments are in list format, but I'm not sure. It may also have to do with having missing dependencies, but I don't see anything in the code that would anticipate.

Has any one come across this exact object not found exception?

Comment: May be you need to reinstall `rlang`

Comment: Try this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table/39525903?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)  Kf

Comment: Like @akrun said, reinstall rlang.  This happened to two of my machines last week, and removing & installing rlang worked.