# R: how to publish Shiny app? problem with dplyr and rlang

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, rlang

I am trying to publish Shiny app.
**Locally everything is working fine**, but when publishing it throws an error:

```
Loading required package: rlang
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.6 is required
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

packages that I am loading (at the beginning of the app.R) are:

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tibble)
```

What might be a problem? How to fix it?
I tried to inlcude `library(rlang)` but no difference. Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove and reinstall `rlang` package. Also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table

Comment: I tried already bo no effect. Locally everything is working fine, but not when publishing (shinyapps.io)

Comment: Can you check the version of  `rlang` with `packageVersion("rlang")`

Comment: It is 0.4.6, all updated, then uniinstalled and reinstalled, tried everything. I see similar problem happened (just locally) to others but as i said, locally everything looks fine and working, but when trying to deploy the app I get this stupid error (same in logs in shinyapps.io dashboard)

Comment: Normally, when you publish your app in shinyapps.io, your app sends all package information (local) to shinyapps.io, so that it installs them. So it should be somehow sending old package information for `rlang`, despite the latest version is installed in your system.

Comment: thanks. must be something on my side. I deployed from another r/rstudio installation and it works fine. Will try clean install or something...

Comment: OK, so the problem was that I had some mess with library paths therefore all the version conflicts. After sorting it out, everything works fine.