# RMarkdown error package/namespace failed to load

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

my rMarkdown doc was working just fine and now it won't knit--I don't know what changed to cause the error.

```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'kableExtra':
onLoad failed in LoadNamespace() for 'kableExtra', details:
call: !is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::metadata$output %in%
error: 'length=3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Execution halted`
```

Full Code below

````
---
title: "CAS Hub Student Usage"
author: "Evelyn Jenkins"
date: "Spring 2023"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(rJava)
library(xlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(kableExtra)
library(grDevices)
library(colorRamps)
library(ggpie)
casog <- read_excel("C:/Users/Acer/Documents/Technically Correct Data1.xlsx", sheet=1)
casmj <- read_excel("C:/Users/Acer/Documents/Technically Correct Data1.xlsx", sheet=4)
as_tibble(casog)
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
#total unique students (remove duplicates)
casog$'CSU ID'=as.numeric(as.character(casog$'CSU ID'))
casnew <- casog[!duplicated(casog$'CSU ID'), ]
narm <- na.omit(casnew$'CSU ID')
casnew
total <- length(narm)
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
#descriptive stat
cascount <- casog %>% count(casog$"CSU ID")
cascountu <- cascount %>% count(cascount$'n')
av <- mean(cascount$n)
avr <- round(av, digits=2)
thr <- cascountu[3,2]
u <- cascountu[1,2]
r <- total - u
```

---
__Total number of students who used the CAS Hub:&nbsp;`r total`__
&ensp;One-time visitors:&nbsp;`r u`
&ensp;Returning visitors:&nbsp;`r r`
&ensp;&ensp;Average number of visits:&nbsp;`r avr`
&ensp;&ensp;Number of students who visited 3+ times:&nbsp;`r thr` 
*excluding 3 FRCC students/visiting students as outliers
---
```{r, include=FALSE}
casg <- casnew %>% count(casnew$'Level')
casg2 <- na.omit(casg)
casg2
colnames(casg2) <- c("Graduate or Undergraduate?", "Number of Students")
as.tibble(casg2)
casg2
```
```{r, echo=FALSE}
casg2 %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, position='left')
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
casm <- casnew %>% count(casnew$'Major')
n <- casm$'n'
m <- unique(casm$'casnew$Major')
m2 <- na.omit(m)
nn <- casmj$'Students'
mm <- casmj$'CAS Major'
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
mchart <- ggplot(data=casm, aes(x=n, y=fct_rev(fct_infreq(m2,n))))
mchart <- mchart + geom_bar(stat="identity") + ggtitle('What majors were in the CAS Hub?') + labs(x='Number of Students', y ='Major') + border(color='black') + bgcolor(color='#DBEADC') + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))

mchart2 <- ggplot(data=casmj, aes(x=nn, y=fct_rev(fct_infreq(mm,nn))))
mchart2 <- mchart2 + geom_bar(stat="identity") + ggtitle('How about just CAS students?') + labs(x='Number of Students', y='Major') + border(color='black') + bgcolor(color='#DBEADC') + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) + scale_y_discrete(labels=c("Animal Science", "Horticulture", "Landscape Architecture", "Equine Science", "Ag and Resource Economics", "Agricultural Business", "Agricultural Education", "Agricultural Biology", "Soil and Crop", "Env and Resource Economics", "Environmental Horticulture"))
```

---



---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
mchart
```
```{r, echo=FALSE}
mchart2
```

---



---
```{r, include=FALSE}
casclass <- casnew[,c(2,10,11,12,13)]
colnames(casclass)[3] ="Class 2"
colnames(casclass)[4] ="Class 3"
colnames(casclass)[5] ="Class 4"
cc1 <- casclass %>% count(casclass$'Class')
cc2 <- casclass %>% count(casclass$'Class 2')
cc3 <- casclass %>% count(casclass$'Class 3')
cc4 <- casclass %>% count(casclass$'Class 4')
colnames(cc2) <- colnames(cc1) 
colnames(cc3) <- colnames(cc1)
colnames(cc4) <- colnames(cc1)
cl <- rbind(cc1, cc2, cc3, cc4)
cl<- cl[complete.cases(cl), ]
cl2 <- cl[!(row.names(cl) %in% c(4,6,14)),]
colnames(cl2)[1]="Classes"
colnames(cl2)[2]="Number of Students"
students <- cl2$"Number of Students"
classes <- cl2$"Classes"
per <- round((n/sum(n))*100, digits=2)
lab <- paste(classes,"(", per, "%", ")")
color <- colorRampPalette(c("#206D07", "#FF7C00", "#C1B00D"))( 16 )
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
casp <- pie(students, labels=lab, main="What classes did students need help with?", radius=1, cex=0.45, col=color)
cl2 %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, position='left')
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
#export
#write.xlsx(casnew, file = "C:/Users/Acer/Documents/Technically Correct Data1.xlsx", sheetName = "New", append = TRUE)
#write.xlsx(casm, file = "C:/Users/Acer/Documents/Technically Correct Data1.xlsx", sheetName = "Majors", append = TRUE)
#write.xlsx(cascount, file = "C:/Users/Acer/Documents/Technically Correct Data1.xlsx", sheetName = "Users", append = TRUE)
#write.xlsx(cascountu, file = "C:/Users/Acer/Documents/Technically Correct Data1.xlsx", sheetName = "Usage"
```
, append = TRUE)
````

I've already tried restarting and uninstalling both R and Rstudio, uninstalling and reinstalling the package named, and every fix listed here [Error: package or namespace load failed for ggplot2 and for data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table)

Nothing has changed except sometimes now it also says I'm trying to install without a mirror set so I'm lost. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What version of `kableExtra` do you have installed? What's the output if you run `install.packages("kableExtra")`?

Comment: @MrFlick It is version 1.3.4 and the output is >package ‘kableExtra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqMRLux\downloaded_packages

Comment: The latest R turns what used to be a warning into an error. Rolling back to 4.2.3 or installing a patched version of `kableExtra` via `devtools::install_github("kupietz/kableExtra")` should do the trick.