# Having a problem to install fixest packages

Tags: r, panel, plm, fixest

Currently I am estimating IV regresssion with panel data. I thought, fixest packages is the good fit for the analysis. After it is showing some warning when I installed, I can't recall the library.

The error is

> library(fixest)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘fixest’:
> .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'fixest', details:
> call: read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,
> error: empty beginning of file

I thought of using plm package instead. I want clustered standard error, and as I understood from the documentation it doesn't have option as fixest has.

Comment: Have you checked similar questions? Seems like a general package-independent problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table I can recommend `fixest` over `plm` for some applications.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is always good practice to include the code that produced the error in addition to the error itself. This will help you receive better answers. Details about the version of R you are using and your machine operating system would also help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.